# How to get a url signature for embedded signing group

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I create an envelop for Signing groups with embedded signing and i try to get a url to sign but when i send json to views/recipient it's availabel to view not to sign.

i send this json to create an envelope

```
   {
   "templateId":null,
   "subject":'Sign',
   "status":"sent",
   "recipients":{
      "signers":[
         {
            "type_x":"Signer",
            "tabs":{
               "signHereTabs":[
                  {
                     "yPosition":null,
                     "xPosition":null,
                     "tabLabel":null,
                     "recipientId":null,
                     "pageNumber":null,
                     "name":"Sign the document",
                     "documentId":"1",
                     "anchorYOffset":"70",
                     "anchorXOffset":"0",
                     "anchorUnits":"pixels",
                     "anchorString":"Customer signature",
                     "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":"false"
                  }
               ],
               "initialHereTabs":[
                  {
                     "yPosition":null,
                     "xPosition":null,
                     "tabLabel":null,
                     "recipientId":"1",
                     "pageNumber":null,
                     "name":null,
                     "documentId":"1",
                     "anchorYOffset":"80",
                     "anchorXOffset":"0",
                     "anchorUnits":"pixels",
                     "anchorString":"Customer Initials",
                     "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":null
                  }
               ]
            },
            "signingGroupId":"1234",
            "routingOrder":1,
            "recipientId":"1",
         }
      ]
   },
   "emailSubject":"Sign the document",
   "documents":[
      {
         "name":"ffffff.pdf",
         "documentId":"1",
         "documentBase64":"xxxxxxxxx=="
      }
   ],
   "accountId":"xxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

I send this json to get a url to sign

POST /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient

```
{
   "xFrameOptionsAllowFromUrl":"xxxxxx",
   "xFrameOptions":"allow_from",
   "userName":"xxxxxx",
   "signingGroup":"1234",
   "signerClientId":null,
   "securityDomain":"xxxxxxxxx",
   "returnUrl":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "recipientId":null,
   "id":"1",
   "email":"xxxxxxxxxx",
   "documentId":null,
   "authenticationMethod":"HTTPBasicAuth",
   "authenticationInstant":null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I found out you cannot use embedded signing for a signing group. A signing group is built such that more than one person can sign and you don't know who it is. It is based on a set of email addresses. These recipients all get the email and any one of them can click that link and sign, but you cannot build an integration that embeds the signing group as a recipient, because you need to know exactly who the signer is when it's embedded.

Comment: When I pass client user id to an envelope that was created for a group it returns the following message: "Captive recipient not allowed to be a signing group."

Comment: Tks Inbar Gazit